# Hadoop distr values to logs table

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I want to make some script which can send logs to HIVE table
That's the problem for me because I don't know how to bash works
I've tried to do this one:

```
hadoop distcp <from> <to>
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "DISTCP ERROR: ${error_msg}"
    exit 1
    fi
```

It works correct but I need to insert the information in HIVE table with logs which looks like:
`source = from, target = to, time_event = start time, status = $?, url = application url, job = job_id`

I don't know how to write script and pass it to bash variables to do insert.

Comment: `<from> <to>` doesn't make sense. Do you mean `"$1" "$2"`, i.e. passing the data via the command line, or do you mean `"$from" "$to"`, i.e. passing the data via the environment? When you write a script, think first how you want to **invoke** it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can do it like <from><to> or $1 and $2, but I don't know how to pull application_id and job_id from distcp

Comment: Can't answer this, since I have never used hadoop, but how would you "pull" them manually, without a script?

Comment: The files themselves should have the fields for the Hive table. This has nothing to do with distcp